# How to get number of buckets, partitioned by and clustered by information without all the other information included in SHOW CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to write  a query that will be run in an automated Jenkins pipeline that returns only the bucketing and partitioning information for a given table. The SHOW CREATE TABLE statement returns the list if the table columns and the partitioned by and bucketing information. I need my query to only return the number of buckets, the clustered by, and partitioned by fields. Alternatively a way to truncate the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE to only those fields I need would also work. Thank you for any help you may have

I have tried to select from the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE
select PARTITIONED BY FROM (SHOW CREATE TABLE schema-name.table-name)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you cant run such SQL on all the tables. You need to run on a specific table `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;`. And then get your data from that output. Else you need to write a py code to store all data into a table and then pick and choose your result.